# Understanding Asynchronous Programming in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

Based on My Understanding , Asynchronous Programming works by executing more than one task simultaneously on a single thread and then the calling thread gets notified when the task is completed , I just cant Understand how a single thread can execute more than one task simultaneously  and whats the difference between Async. Programming and Multi-threading .

Answer (score 1):

With Asynchronous Programming one thread manages multiple resources which are performing concurrent actions e.g. it could be waiting for one or more network connections to respond, it could be waiting for a disk operation, it could be waiting for other threads to perform the actions.

> Async. Programming and Multi-threading

With multithreading, you have multiple threads all working as peers to perform multiple tasks at the same time.

With asynchronous programming, you have one thread which starts jobs to be executed by other threads (possibly on other machines), and when they are finished perform other actions. i.e.all the coordination is done through one thread.  This is be developed rather like a single threaded process but still benefit from multiple CPUs.

Answer (score 0):

Both multithreading and asynchronous programming are kinds of parallel programming. In multithreading, the minimal part (which is sequential and does not contain parallel parts) is a thread.
In asynchronous programming, the minimal part is asynchronous procedure call (ACP).

Each thread has its own call stack, which consumes considerable amount of memory (0.5..1.0 MB). As a result, practical limit is about 10000 threads per process.

An ACP has no own call stack, it is executed on a thread borrowed from some thread pool. When ACP waits for input data, it does not use any thread and so consumes relatively small amount of memory, and we can have millions of ACP in the same process.
But asynchronous programming is more tricky than multithreading programming, and has more traps.

"executing more than one task simultaneously on a single thread " - no. A user's thread can spawn many ACP and they will be executed in parallel, but on worker threads of some threadpool (which can include the originating thread). Each worker thread executes asynchronous tasks sequentially, one by one.